# How to best limit JVM memory inside docker container?

Tags: memory-management, jvm, containers, heap-memory, docker-container

`-Xmx` flag [is used to](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/xms/): set the the maximum heap size

while the
`-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` [is used to](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/xxinitialrampercentage/): specify the maximum size of the Java heap as a percentage of the total memory available to the VM

Is it better to use `-Xmx` or `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage`? When should each be used?

Comment: Closed as a duplicate, because the discussion under the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54076834/3448419) is exacly about your question.

Comment: @apangin I saw that Q&A, but it didn't guide me on criteria for when to use each...

Comment: In our systems, we use `-Xmx` in 100% cases, and I explained in the linked discussion why we do so. I also told how `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` works. How can I help you further to make a decision?

Comment: Let me watch your video first, and then I'll decide if I have more questions :)